# How to pause / resume any external process under Windows?

Tags: windows, process, process-management

I am looking for different ways to pause and resume programmatically a particular process via its process ID under Windows XP.

[Process suspend/resume tool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/pausep.aspx) does it with `SuspendThread` / `ResumeThread` but warns about multi-threaded programs and deadlock problems.

[PsSuspend](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897540.aspx) looks okay, but I wonder if it does anything special about deadlocks or uses another method?

Prefered languages : C++ / Python

Comment: A SEO comment follows: PsSuspend looks like a windows equivalent of Linux/UNIX's `kill -SIGSTOP` or `kill -SIGCONT` (and even `killall`).

Answer (score 5):

If you "debug the debugger" (for instance, using `logger.exe` to trace all API calls made by `windbg.exe`), it appears that the debugger uses `SuspendThread()`/`ResumeThread()` to suspend all of the threads in the process being debugged.

PsSuspend may use a different way of suspending processes (I'm not sure), but it is still possible to hang other processes: if the process you're suspending is holding a shared synchronization object that is needed by another process, you may block that other process from making any progress. If both programs are well-written, they should recover when you resume the one that you suspended, but not all programs are well-written. And if this causes your program that is doing the suspending to hang, then you have a deadlock.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this does the job, but with ProcessExplorer from MS Systernals you can suspend a process.

It's been said here: https://superuser.com/a/155263 and I found it there too.

Comment: Wow! This is it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010165/how-to-suspend-resume-a-process-in-windows) and you also have psutil for python that you can use it like that:

```
>>> import psutil
>>> pid = 7012
>>> p = psutil.Process(pid)
>>> p.suspend()
>>> p.resume()
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/pausep.aspx on few softwares:

it works fine.

PsSuspend and Pausep are two valid options.

Comment: If you're careful in using it then it works fine.  If you use it to create a deadlock then you create a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

So, after I found about [UniversalPauseButton](https://github.com/ryanries/UniversalPauseButton), Googling for this ("windows SIGSTOP"), getting this question as the first search result (thanks Ilia K. [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100480/how-to-pause-resume-any-external-process-under-windows#comment4274004_100480) did its job), and reading the answers, I went back to checkout the code.

[Apparently](https://github.com/ryanries/UniversalPauseButton/blob/72c7e53c5471c15b9fd5f5fc7cfe1d346592aa66/Main.cpp#L17), it uses undocumented NT kernel and Win32 APIs `_NtSuspendProcess`, `_NtResumeProcess` and `_HungWindowFromGhostWindow`.

PsSuspend, the utility you mentioned and linked to probably uses these APIs, I couldn't verify this, the source code isn't supplied, only executables and a EULA, you can probably figure that out by disassembling the binary but it's against the EULA.

so, to answer your specific question, checkout [UniversalPauseButton](https://github.com/ryanries/UniversalPauseButton)'s main.**cpp**, [basically](https://github.com/ryanries/UniversalPauseButton/blob/72c7e53c5471c15b9fd5f5fc7cfe1d346592aa66/Main.cpp#L314) you call `_NtSuspendProcess(ProcessHandle)` and `_NtResumeProcess(ProcessHandle)`, `ProcessHandle` being the handle of the process you want to pause or resume.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a good reason why there is no SuspendProcess() function in Windows. Having such a function opens the door for an unstable system. You shall not suspend a process unless you created that process yourself.
If you wrote that process yourself, you could use an event (see ::SetEvent() etc. in MSDN) or another kind of messaging to trigger a pause command in the process.

Comment: Linux with it's Ctrl+Z process pause function is quite stable.