# Java process suspend and continue

Tags: java, linux, windows, process, suspend

I'm looking for a solution capable of doing this on Java:

- Spawn a process.
- Suspend it (like kill -STOP does in Linux).
- Continue a suspended process (like kill -CONT in Linux).
- Read/Write their standard input/output pipes at runtime.
- Working on (at least) Linux and Windows.

As far as I know, the Java standar only implements first and fourth, but not the second neither the third.

What could I do?

Comment: You don't know far enough. You could use [`wait`/`notify`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html). You could use the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://shazsterblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/comparison-of-countdownlatch.html) package.

Comment: In addition, you can execute shell commands within java through which you can achieve 2 and 3 easily. May be there are some other ways too.

Comment: That solution applies for threads. Does it work for process too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of doing "directly" from Java.

You will need to do something specific for Windows / Linux, in each case executing an external program, or invoking native code.

On Linux, you can use `kill` as you suggest.

On Windows, you can call `SuspendThread()`, or maybe you can launch the SysInternals tool 'PsSuspend'.  There is some information that may help you here:

[How to pause / resume any external process under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100480/how-to-pause-resume-any-external-process-under-windows)

[How to suspend/resume a process in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010165/how-to-suspend-resume-a-process-in-windows)

If you wish to invoke native code from Java, JNIWrapper may help you.

Also, if you need the PIDs of the spawned processes, then you may need to *launch* them via native code also, as Java will not give you their PIDs.

Comment: So, can't I use wait/notify as Boris the Spider suggested?

Comment: No, wait/notify are used to control _threads_ within your Java program, whereas you want to control external processes.

Comment: JNIWrapper seems not to be freeware. Is there another solution involving only free technology?

Comment: Write the native Windows code yourself, i.e. use Visual C++ Express edition to produce a DLL.  Make calls from your Java program to this DLL using raw JNI.