# How to pause a selected program through python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So im trying to make a TAS maker for games but I can't find a way to pause a program from python {ex.: pause Minecraft then when a key is pressed unpause for 1/30 of a second [to advance 1 frame] add a key you want to be pressed on that frame [then repeat]} I don't even know what to put into google.

Comment: What exactly are you trying  to do?. Graphical programs might not behave well if they're stopped. Under POSIX you could try to send SIGSTOP via a `kill` command. For windows, check https://stackoverflow.com/q/100480/1477064

Comment: @xvan just trying to temporarily stop it but it still being displayed so you can unpause and play from where you left off like the cheat engine function [set program speed] then set it to 0

Comment: Easiest way should be to use the signals. Another way would be to control a debugger from python and use it to launch / stop the application. Maybe something like pygdbmi